# Is factorial the restriction of some elementary function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

Hölder's theorem says that Gamma function is very non-elementary, but it does not exclude the possibility that factorial is the restriction of some elementary function to natural numbers. The answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392728/proof-that-the-factorial-is-nonelementary) question on SE says that is impossible, but someone in the comment pointed out an issue, and I think the comment is right, which leads to the question:

1. Is factorial the restriction of some elementary function to natural numbers?

Or maybe let's start with something easier:

2. Does Stirling's formula $\displaystyle\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$ ever produce an integer (asking for rational seems too difficult)? It certainly cannot produce integers twice.

Comment: If the answer to (2) were “yes” then $\pi$ and $e$ would be algebraically dependent, which nobody believes to be the case. The algebraic independence is unproved but would follow from Schanuel’s conjecture.

Comment: Presumably, $n=0$ doesn't count.

Comment: @KConrad I know. That's why I asked about integer not rational. Does that seem any easier?

Comment: @1830rbc03 no it's all hopeless at present.  Do you agree the answer to (1) is far more likely to be "no" rather than "yes"?

Comment: @KConrad Of course I expect the answers to both to be "no". Is (1) open too? When I wrote the question I thought (2) must be easier than (1) but that may not be the case. Does (1) somehow follow from the non-elementarity of Gamma function?

Comment: @1830rbc03 I know nothing about such things, but they seem like totally hopeless problems at present.